# React function is not being called back in render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am creating a movie searching app with React, Redux and Firebase. I created a function(isPresentMovie) to verify whether the movie has been in Fb or not, and my expectation is that either "Add Movie"/"Remove Movie" button is being returned depending on the result of verification.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {  addFav, removeFav, getDetail } from '../../store/actions/getDetailAction'
import { firestoreConnect } from 'react-redux-firebase';
import { compose } from 'redux'


const button = {
    marginLeft:'10px',
    marginRight:'10px',
}

export class Favorite extends Component {

        handleRemove = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.props.removeFav()
        };

        handleAdd = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            this.props.addFav()
        }

    isPresentMovie = () => {
        const validation = this.props.favorites.filter(favorite => favorite.authorId == this.props.auth.uid).find(favorite => favorite.imdbID == this.props.movie.imdbID); 

        if(validation == undefined){
            return (<button type="submit" className="btn btn-danger btn-bg mt-1" onClick={this.handleRemove} style={button}>Remove From Favorite</button>);
        } else {
            return (<button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-bg mt-1" onClick={this.handleAdd} style={button}>Add To Favorite</button>);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="d-flex">
               {this.isPresentMovie()}  
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    favorites: state.firestore.ordered.favorites,
    auth: state.firebase.auth,
    movie: state.movie.movie,
})

export default compose(
    connect(mapStateToProps,{ addFav, removeFav, getDetail }),
    firestoreConnect([
        { collection: 'favorites' }
    ])
)(Favorite);
```

Issue 1: Although I use arrow function, the function is not being called in render().The error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined" Tried with .bind(this), the result was same.

Issue 2: I initially suspected that it was not properly rendered out, but if I did not use any methods inside the function, it displayed correctly.

If it is because of the methods, is there any alternative way to verify data in Fb against API data? Or with another way, I can validate data based on the function I created?

Comment: works for me. I thinks the problem is with the calling. Are you sure the firestoreConnect adds the prop favorites at least an empty array all the time?

Answer (score 1):

The `favorites` prop isn't defined, probably because the data is in the processing of coming from firebase on the initial load. Another problem you will have is that your buttons need to have the `key` prop. While favorites is undefined, you can just render null from isPresent, try this:

```js
isPresentMovie = () => {
  if (!Array.isArray(this.props.favorites)) {
    return null;
  }

  const validation = this.props.favorites.filter(favorite => favorite.authorId == this.props.auth.uid).find(favorite => favorite.imdbID == this.props.movie.imdbID); 

  if(validation == undefined){
    return (<button key="no-validation" type="submit" className="btn btn-danger btn-bg mt-1" onClick={this.handleRemove} style={button}>Remove From Favorite</button>);
  } else {
    return (<button key="validation" type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-bg mt-1" onClick={this.handleAdd} style={button}>Add To Favorite</button>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I thought the function was not being called, but it seems it was, but the thing is 'this.props.favorites' was not defined properly.. I tried @royranger 's one, and it works well. Thank you so much anyway:)

Answer (score 0):

> Issue 1: Although I use arrow function, the function is not being
>   called in render().The error saying "TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'filter' of undefined" Tried with .bind(this), the result was same.

The fact that it is showing this error means that it is indeed calling your `isPresentMovie` function. But the issue is that `this.props.favorites` is undefined.

Try a check before calling `filter` on it, ie

```
const validation = this.props.favorites && this.props.favorites.filter(favorite => favorite.authorId == this.props.auth.uid).find(favorite => favorite.imdbID == this.props.movie.imdbID);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance! This worked well! I've never thought I needed to define 'this.props.favorites &&'  prior to the actual statement...